# SVN and accented characters

Tags: svn, character-encoding

I have a subversion repository that I administer. When I try to add a file which has accented (non-ASCII) characters in its name, the server refuses the command. The server is running on Ubuntu, the client is Eclipse on Windows.

I could not find anything in the [SVN FAQ](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html) about accented characters in filenames, nor in the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). I know that having accented characters in sourcecode file's name is probably not such a good idea, but ... this is the requirement ...

Any idea of where to find the documentation ?

Comment: The add fails, or the commit fails? What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that on your server you have apr-iconv installed. Without apr-iconv, Subversion can not convert utf8 strings and will throw an error if it fails to do so.

You might also get more information from the server error log.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20151012053153/http://www.juretta.com/log/2007/05/09/svn_can_t_convert_string_from_utf-8_to_native_encoding_/) sounds relevant, but it's hard when you haven't given the exact error you get from your server.

Still, sounds like sound advice: check your local system's filename encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Check **svn:eol-style**